# How to check if a website supports PWA using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a Node.js project and I need to determine whether any website supports Progressive Web App (PWA) functionality.

I tried using `axios` and `cheerio` to check whether the website has a valid service worker and web manifest. It can work only with standard cases like Starbucks and BWM.

Is there any way to determine the custom valid service worker URL or any approaching way to resolve the task?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y question. For what reason would you need to know this information?

Comment: The project owner wants to create several collections of PWA applications from a list of websites.